# How to improve performance in Hibernate polymorphic query when using table per class strategy?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, table-per-class

When using table per class strategy, polymorphic query looks like this:

```
SELECT <some cols> 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      parent_id,
      entity1_col,
      entity2_col,
      1 as clazz_ 
    FROM 
      entity_table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      parent_id,
      entity1_col,
      entity2_col,
      2 as clazz_ 
    FROM 
      entity_table2 
  ) abstract_entity 
WHERE 
  abstract_entity.parent_id = X
```

We can see that if we have a lot of rows in entity_table1 and entity_table2, this query can lead to performance issue.

I am using Spring-data & Hibernate and this request is generated when fetching a OneToMany relation on a parent entity.

My question is : why Hibernate generates such request though it is restricting selected rows on parent_id that is common to entity_table1 & entity_table2 ?

Is there a way to have Hibernate generating a SQL request that look like this:

```
SELECT <some cols>
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      parent_id,
      entity1_col,
      entity2_col,
      1 as clazz_ 
    FROM 
      entity_table1 
    WHERE 
      parent_id=X
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      parent_id,
      entity1_col,
      entity2_col,
      2 as clazz_ 
    FROM 
      entity_table2 
    WHERE 
      parent_id=X
  ) abstract_entity
```

Having "WHERE parent_id=X" in each request in FROM ? This way no performance issue when fetching relation on parent entity.

Thanks !

Comment: This question seems  more suited for the Hibernate Zulip chat: https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user

Comment: thanks, i have posted the question on hibernate.suplit. I'll put the answer on stackoverflow it i get any.

Comment: I'm confused, what's the difference? Do the above result in different query plans for you? I would expect a decent query optimizer to predicate-push in the first scenario

Comment: I agree that the DB should be able to push-down the predicate during optimization. If not, I would consider switching to a more capable database.

Comment: @crizzis, yes, you are right. I was wondering about performance issue (Hibernate warns about it when using table per class strategy) but was able to validate that it is OK even with with some data in entity tables (about 3M rows). So Mysql optimizer does correctly its job, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I made a modification based on hibernate 5.6.3 to pushdown the predict for polymorphic query when using table-per-concrete-class strategy. Please refer to https://github.com/kerler/hibernate-orm/tree/main_5.6.3-open-care.

After modification, for code “Query q = s.createQuery( "from Being h where h.identity = :name1 or h.identity = :name2 or h.identity = :name2" );” in hibernate UT case UnionSubclassTest.java::testNestedUnionedSubclasses(), the SQL generated by hibernate is like:

```
00:37:43,945 DEBUG SQL:144 - 
    select
        being0_.bid as bid1_2_,
        being0_.ident as ident2_2_,
        being0_.location as location3_2_,
        being0_.sex as sex1_6_,
        being0_.salary as salary1_4_,
        being0_.species as species1_0_,
        being0_.hive as hive2_0_,
        being0_.clazz_ as clazz_ 
    from
        ( select
            bid,
            ident,
            location,
            sex,
            salary,
            null as species,
            null as hive,
            2 as clazz_ 
        from
            employees 
        where
            ident=? 
            or ident=? 
            or ident=? 
        union
        all select
            bid,
            ident,
            location,
            sex,
            null as salary,
            null as species,
            null as hive,
            1 as clazz_ 
        from
            humans 
        where
            ident=? 
            or ident=? 
            or ident=? 
        union
        all select
            bid,
            ident,
            location,
            null as sex,
            null as salary,
            species,
            hive,
            3 as clazz_ 
        from
            aliens 
        where
            ident=? 
            or ident=? 
            or ident=? 
    ) being0_ 
where
    being0_.ident=? 
    or being0_.ident=? 
    or being0_.ident=?
```

Comment: The modified hibernate is not published to any repo online. So, to use the modified hibernate, execute 'gradle publishToMavenLocal' to publish the module into the Maven local repository (typically at $USER_HOME/.m2/repository), along with its POM file and other metadata.